# Java NIO HTTP server and Browser

Tags: java, sockets, http, network-programming, nio

I coded a small server with NIO while walking normally except that the server can not make broadcasts at certain times to my clients because of the closure of the channel. Is there a solution against this problem? I make http requests via the browser.

Thank you for your help.
Cordially.

Comment: The simple answer is yes, you can keep the socket open.  I don't know why you feel you need to close it.  BTW nice pic. ;)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I wish to make HTTP requests, if I close the socket I get my answer if the application runs in a loop so I'm forced to close the socket. The problem is that after the server can not make broadcasts with new updated information to my clients

Comment: Your browser must support persisted HTTP 1.1 connections. If it does you can keep the connection open and the browser can reuse it many times.  If you browser is not using these persisted connection you have no choice but to close the connection as this is what the browser expects.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection for more details.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse mon navigateur gère les connexions persistantes je vous met le code qui écrit le Str au channel mon code actuel débutant avec NIO, j'ai peut-être glissé une erreur.

Comment: private static void channelWrite(SocketChannel channel, ByteBuffer writeBuffer) {
long nbytes = 0;
long toWrite = writeBuffer.remaining();
 
try {
 
 while (writeBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
       channel.write(writeBuffer);
 } 
  channel.close();
}
catch (ClosedChannelException cce) {
 infos("problème");
}
catch (Exception e) {
} 

// get ready for another write if needed
writeBuffer.rewind();
}

Comment: The code look fine if you have to close the connection.  I would check whether your browser expects it must be closed or not.  Most browsers today support persisted connections.

Comment: If I remove the channel.close (), the application runs in a loop without a response. Apparently I have to close the socket, I'll save the socket in an array application and connect to each broadcasts, is not heavy like process?

Comment: It is. It would more efficient if the client could support a persisted connection. Opening and closing connections can be 10x more expensive than the request itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem comes because the  browserdoes not manage to read intoxicates it of my HTTP request because there is not. I owe in my opinion if I am on the right track to add one intoxicates for every answer which the  server is going to send to dismiss. Is there a specific bookshop for this  genre of case? Thank you again of your help and patience.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question?  Intoxicates means to get drunk. ;)

Comment: As I make requests via the browser, the browser expects to receive a header to know what to do (hence the problem of writing). Is there a specific library to overcome this problem to add a connection: keep-alive, content type, etc.?

Comment: The problem is your browser has to support and request HTTP 1.1 keep alive.  This is not something you can change  in your proxy if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look into [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) technology. Of course you browser should support Http1.1 keep-alive